error en Gralde - transforms-4
Tengo un grave error, al crear un nuevo proyecto o al abrir los existentes.

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
C:\Users\ramon.gradle\caches\transforms-4\225d20a5270ab7154acc4efd4ab8c329\metadata.bin
(El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)   at
org.gradle.internal.execution.history.impl.DefaultImmutableWorkspaceMetadataStore.loadWorkspaceMetadata(DefaultImmutableWorkspaceMetadataStore.java:45)

Leí en este post Al crear un proyecto en Android Studio. Error ...cache.properties (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
cosa que no me a solucionado nada
También os comento que el archivo que no encuentra esta en

C:\Users\ramon.gradle\caches\

pero como una carpeta y dentro

\transforms-4\225d20a5270ab7154acc4efd4ab8c329\transformed\original\android-gradle.jar

Pregunto, alguna solución

Bueno la única solución que e encontrado es restaurar el equipo y todo funcionando.
